# Inserting specific fields into a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables in a mysql db. A joining table, Author table, Output Table, and a Person table. I had to import a csv file that had an outputID and personID but only have access to the author names column, so i've added an auto increment primary key to the author table.

I want the query I've made to insert the author Id's into the joining table where the specific author related to the ID matches the specific outputID.

The following query keeps inserting the author Id's but all at the bottom of the the joining table, without any matching output id

```
INSERT INTO output(a_fk) 
SELECT a.Author_ID 
FROM authors a 
INNER JOIN wholecsv w ON a.Author_Names = w.a_Author 
INNER JOIN outputlist ot ON ot.Output_ID = w.a_ID 
INNER JOIN output o ON o.Output_ID = ot.Output_ID
```

Comment: INSERT will always create a NEW row

Answer (score 0):

> The following query keeps inserting the author Id's but all at the bottom of the the joining table, without any matching output id

That's what `INSERT` does : adding new records to the table.

It looks like you are actually looking for an `UPDATE` query. For this, you need to adjust the `JOIN` logic so it goes from `output` to `authors`, like :

```
UPDATE output o
INNER JOIN outputlist ot ON o.Output_ID = ot.Output_ID
INNER JOIN wholecsv ON ot.Output_ID = w.a_ID 
INNER JOIN authors  ON a.Author_Names = w.a_Author 
SET o.a_fk = a.Author_ID
```